# Grails view and filter events by user Id

Tags: grails, view, filtering

I have a Domain class with:

class Events {
    static belongsTo = [Sponsor, Old]

```
String evento
Date data = new Date()
String local
Sponsor sponsor
Old old

static constraints = {
    data(blank: false)
    local(blank: false)
    evento(blank: false)
}
```

}

I generate views and controllers automatically (generate-views) and now when I logged in, in my view personalizada I have every events... How I filter the results by User Id (login)?

My page is:

```
...
<div id="list-events" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
        <h1>Agenda</h1>
        <br>
        <table>
        <thead>
                <tr>

                    <g:sortableColumn property="data" controller ="events" title="${message(code: 'events.data.label', default: 'Evento') } " />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="local" controller ="events" title="${message(code: 'events.local.label', default: 'Local')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="evento" controller ="events" title="${message(code: 'events.evento.label', default: 'Data')}" />

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${eventsInstanceList}" status="i" var="eventsInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${eventsInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: eventsInstance, field: "evento")}</g:link></td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: eventsInstance, field: "local")}</td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: eventsInstance, field: "data")}</td>

                </tr>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate total="${eventsInstanceCount ?: 0}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>...
```

and in the _form:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: eventsInstance.old, field: 'data', 'error')} required">
<label for="data">
    <g:message code="events.data.label" default="Data" />
    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:datePicker name="data" precision="day"  value="${eventsInstance?.data}"  />
```

*
    
    



    
        
        *
    
    



    
        
        *
    
    



    
        
        *

And my controller:

```
class EventsController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond Events.list(params), model:[eventsInstanceCount: Events.count()]
}

def show(Events eventsInstance) {
    respond eventsInstance
}

def create() {
    respond new Events(params)
}

@Transactional
def save(Events eventsInstance) {
    if (eventsInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (eventsInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond eventsInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    eventsInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'eventsInstance.label', default: 'Events'), eventsInstance.id])
            redirect eventsInstance
        }
        '*' { respond eventsInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}

def edit(Events eventsInstance) {
    respond eventsInstance
}

@Transactional
def update(Events eventsInstance) {
    if (eventsInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (eventsInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond eventsInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    eventsInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'Events.label', default: 'Events'), eventsInstance.id])
            redirect eventsInstance
        }
        '*'{ respond eventsInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}

@Transactional
def delete(Events eventsInstance) {

    if (eventsInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    eventsInstance.delete flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'Events.label', default: 'Events'), eventsInstance.id])
            redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
    }
}

protected void notFound() {
    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'eventsInstance.label', default: 'Events'), params.id])
            redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
    }
}
```

}

How I filter every events associate a specific login?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the controller. This is the line you need to edit:

```
respond Events.list(params), model:[eventsInstanceCount: Events.count()]
```

Change it to something like

```
def myEvents = Events.findAllBySponsor(sponsor, params)
def allMyEventsCount = Events.countBySponsor(sponsor)
respond myEvents, model:[eventsInstanceCount: allMyEventsCount]
```

where sponsor is the user you want to filter by. (I'm assuming that the logged-in users are event sponsors)

Note that if you have multiple events with the same value for the specified sort parameter, your results may not remain in the same order as you refresh or page through the results. One way to prevent that is to use multiple sort criteria where one of them is always on a unique-valued property, such as a database id. I generally implement this with Criteria. May I refer you to http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying.

Comment: That is a bad idea.  You are calling Events.findAllBySponsor(sponsor) and then invoking .size() on what that returns.  That means every record has to be retrieved and run through the whole ORM contraption so you can count them.  A better idea is calling Events.countBySponsor(sponsor).

Comment: I changed my answer to incorporate Jeffs' feedback.

Comment: @Jeff, Is there something like Events.countAllWhere() or the equivalent? btw I could not find countBy() in the GORM chapter of the Grails doc, only in the reference pages.

Comment: There is no countAllWhere() and I don't know if there is an equivalent because I don't know what you think that would do or what an equivalent would be.  You can do things like use withCriteria and express a count projection.  Is that what you are looking for?

I believe the only docs in the user guide for countBy are the docs at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/countBy.html.